# Intermediate textbook in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I am looking for a Linear Algebra textbook that for those who just finished elementary Linear Algebra. I just finished Introductory to Linear Algebra by Strang and read to Least Squares and Orthogonality. I found a textbook that is advanced linear algebra but was wondering if anyone knows a text that is for those who should cover anything that is in between elementary and advanced level before jumping to advanced level.

Comment: Have you checked out David Lay's Linear Algebra?

Comment: @Jossie I have. The text follows relatively in the same approach as Lang's far as material wise.

Comment: What specifically are you looking for? Are you looking to develop proof skills or to get more applications? And what books that are "advanced" have you looked at?

Comment: @TedShifrin Bit of both would be nice but I would prefer a text that is more proof based.

Comment: I second the recommendation of Insel, Spence, Friedberg, but to some students that's advanced. Hence my attempt to calibrate things with my question about what *you* consider advanced.

Answer (score 1):

The text "Linear Algebra" by Spence, Insel, & Friedberg fits nicely into the "intermediate" category. I've taught a couple of courses using this text as a follow up to the typical introduction to linear algebra.

http://books.google.com/books?id=x7CLMQAACAAJ&dq=spence+insel+friedberg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JFcrUoRZ8rjgA-CjgAg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAQ

You can get copies of old editions for less than $10.

It recovers all of the basic linear algebra topics, but with proof. It also has sections on topics like dual spaces. It has a couple of chapters covering canonical forms like rational form and Jordan form. Most importantly, overall its pretty easy to read.

[Note: Don't confuse this with the authors' "Elementary Linear Algebra" whose name says it all.]